# Created user, so now who owns the tables created?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, schema

Most of my background comes from `sql server`, so I'm having a difficult time with Oracle terminology.

In `sql server`, I create database `Sales` and create objects under `Sales` with `create table dbo.MyTable {...}`. Now I can query this table with `select * from Sales.dbo.MyTable`. In `Management Studio` I'll see my table `dbo.Sales` under `Sales` & `Tables`. It's clear that these objects are related to Sales.

I'm trying to do the same thing with Oracle. Apparently, [everything can reside under the same database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71544/remove-ora-01100database-already-mounted) and what changes is the schema.

So, after installing Oracle XE 11.2 I was able to log on to SID `XE` with user `sys`.

Once I logged in with `sys`, I created a user `SALESMANAGER` and granted permissions:

```
CREATE USER salesmanager IDENTIFIED BY mypassword;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA TO salesmanager;
```

Now I have a user and an empty schema called `SALESMANAGER`. I've logged on as `SALESMANAGER` and I then created table `Totals`. Now the table *falls* under schema `SALESMANAGER`.

I don't want them under that schema; I want them to fall under `SALES`. If I create another user `SALES`, then I'll create another schema.

I know my logic's wrong, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want the tables in `SALES` then create a user called `SALES` and use it to create the tables. Then they'll be in `SALES` and not in `SALESMANAGER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you said is correct.

If you want user `SALES` to contain your tables, why didn't you create it (but created `SALESMANAGER` instead)?

So: connect as `SYS` again, then

```
drop user salesmanager cascade;
CREATE USER sales IDENTIFIED BY mypassword;

grant create session, create table to sales;
```

Don't grant privileges you don't need. Especially, don't grant DBA (which is a powerful role). If it turns out that you'd need additional privileges (of course you will - such as `create view`, `create sequence`, ...), grant them.

Now, connect as `sales` and create the `totals` table.

If you want to keep the `salesmanager` user, don't drop it. User `sales` can then grant certain privileges on its tables to another users - `salesmanager` included. Connected as `sales`:

```
create table totals (id number, total number);
insert into totals (id, total) values (1, 100);
grant select on totals to salesmanager;
```

Connect as `salesmanager`:

```
select * From sales.totals;    --> precede table name with its owner
```

Comment: Thanks. But then wouldn't I have an empty schema `salesmanager` (as opposed to the user) that I will never use?

Comment: Yes. That's why I asked why did you create it, if you don't need it.

Comment: I need the user `salesmanager` but I don't need the schema `salesmanager`.

Comment: Schema = user (+ its objects). You can't have what you want.

Comment: I guess my thought process is skewed towards sql-server: it's like creating several empty databases (ie. _SALESMANAGER_, _JOE_, _RALPH_, _SALES_) so that they call all see the tables in _SALES_.

Comment: But You're right. I just have to get used to this new way of looking at objects.

Comment: Right; although similar, still quite different. When in Rome, do as Romans do :)